# Adding JavaScript to Classic ASP (new to this)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, asp-classic, popup

I've got a website in ASP.NET that has a little cookie pop up warning when people visit the site. What I wasn't to do is replicate this but for a site that is written in Classic ASP (not my fault) I know the code works, because it works on the current site. How can I reference JavaScript and where does it go in relation to the page? I'm really new to all this so sorry if my questions seem really silly. Thanks in advance for any help. this is the code I'm using:

div id="cookieConsentRequest" runat="server" visible="true

```
            <p><span class="queryIcon"></span>some text here                <a href="#" class="acceptCookiesAnchor acceptCookieSmall acceptCookie" runat="server">I accept</a>
            <a href="Javascript:;" class="infoCookie" title="Tell me more about these cookies">Click here for more info</a>
            <a href="Javascript:;" id="alertBannerHide" class="hideButton" title="Hide this">Hide</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!--[if IE 6]>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.alertBanner').css("top", ($(window).height() - 29));
            });
        </script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.alertBanner').css("left", (($(window).width() / 2) - 360));
                $('.alertBanner').delay(1000).slideDown('slow');
                $('#alertBannerHide, a.denyCookie').click(function () {
                    $('.alertBanner').slideUp('slow');
                    $('.cookieInfoWindow').fadeOut('fast');
                });
                $('.cookieInfoWindow').css("left", (($(window).width() / 2) - 320));
                $('a.acceptCookie, .infoCookie').click(function () {
                    $('.cookieInfoWindow').fadeIn('fast');
                });
                $('#cookieInfoWindowHide, .cookieInfoWindow a.denyCookie').click(function () {
                    $('.cookieInfoWindow').fadeOut('fast');
                    $('.alertBanner').slideUp('slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div class="cookieInfoWindow">
            <h3><a href="Javascript:;" id="cookieInfoWindowHide" class="hideButton" title="Hide this">Hide</a>Cookies used on this web site</h3><br />

            <p>some text here</p><br />
            <p>some text here <a href="http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55539" class="externalLinkWhite"
             title="Read more about Google Analytics (external link)">Google Analytics</a> some text here.</p><br />
            <p>some text herep><br />
             <p>For more information on how cookies are used please visit the following websites:</p>
             <ul>
                <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/info/cookies.mspx" class="externalLinkWhite" title="Information about cookies on Microsoft.com (external link)">Microsoft Cookie Information</a><br /><br />
                <a href="http://www.allaboutcookies.org/" class="externalLinkWhite" title="All about computer cookies (external link)">All About Cookies</a>
             </ul>
            <p>
                <a id="acceptCookiesAnchor" href="#" class="acceptCookie" runat="server">Yes, I accept the use of cookies as outlined above</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>-->
```

Sorry about the state of it.

Comment: what do you mean by "reference Java"?

Comment: maybe you should show how you are doing this in .net, to make things clearer.

Comment: You mean JavaScript that is used to create the cookie? It's exactly the same both in classic ASP and ASP.NET just have it inside the `.asp` page itself in the `<head>` section.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ , Just added the code above, tried in ASP but some of it wont work as it's .NET only. sorry for the late reply, I couldn't log in for ages

Comment: I don't see anything related to Java or .NET in that code.

Comment: I tried it on one ASP site using WebMatrix and it told me some of the code was .NET just tried it on the site I wanted and it didn't complain. BUT, this is the one I'm taking (http://www.claremonthoteldouglas.com/) when I put it on the ASP site, it just ends up as a bit of text in the bottom left corner stating '
By continuing to browse the site you are agreeing to our use of cookies. <a>I accept</a> <a>Click here for more info</a> <a>Hide</a>    then further across --->  <a>HideCookies</a>used on this web site'   (The <a> is just there to illustrate it's a hyperlink)

Comment: Are you referencing jQuery UI?

Comment: @jaypeagi   jQuery UI? no....sorry, this must seem so simple to people, I just can't get my head around it though. only been learning html etc. for a couple of months

Comment: @OllieHamon sorry it doesn't look like you need jQuery UI but you do need jQuery. I'll post a full answer if you don't have jQuery

Comment: @jaypeagi Yes please. That would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a part of the browser. You provide the JavaScript you want the browser to run inline with HTML or as a `.js` file referenced in the HTML.

jQuery, to quote [their website](http://jquery.com), is "a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers".

Importantly, jQuery provides the `$` syntax and the `css`, `slideDown`, `fadeUp`, etc functions your code uses.

Therefore your code must reference the jQuery library. This is easily done by adding the following line *before* (in the `<head>` is OK but not necessarily best practice) any of your jQuery code (JavaScript using `$` or `jQuery`):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

This adds a reference to the latest (at time of posting) jQuery code hosted on their servers. You can also [download the library here](http://jquery.com/download/) and reference it locally.

Comment: Thank you, That sort of helped. (I added a page load event to check and the new window would open) but it still wont render. I pulled all the css through, and pictures etc.....

Comment: Please explain in more detail. A JSFIddle may help too.

Comment: don't know what that is sorry. if you go to this site --> http://www.claremont.im the little cookie warning that posp up at the bottom is what this script is from. when put into an ASP page, the text shows (split over 9 lines) but it doesn't come up in a little box or anything, just sits at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You seem to be missing the images

Comment: the pictures are certainly there, well in the correct folder etc. I'm a bit unsure what you mean

Comment: I just copied some JavaScript from the net, ran it whilst the file was on my desktop and it worked. when I put the file into the root of the site though. It wouldn't do anything! why would it fall over just because of this? (and yes I did change the path ) would it be a similar reason to this one falling over? not important just curious